UMG Drawing Delay
Is there any way to delay the re-rendering of a widget when you clear its children?
I am trying to clear my inventory widget of all the children widgets, then re-add them (sort of a clear and refresh mechanic) but when I do so, the inventory widget flickers (in the time between clearing and re-adding the children widgets).
My question is: Is there a way to delay the rendering of a widget, pending the completion of some code, then re-enable the rendering?
I tried several rather hacky approaches including a render target, and a frame rate limiter, but these proved to be unreliable or introduced unwanted behavior.

I ended up solving it by only invalidating the child widget I care about and setting a flag in each item to indicate if it was already in the inventory, to prevent reprocessing items. It's a simple check of a Boolean value, which is cleared when the ondrag event is fired for the widget representing the item in my player's inventory.

